# How to fix preg_replace warning?

Tags: php, preg-replace

After PHP update do 5.4.19 faced a new warning which did not exist before. It says: `Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in ... on line 645`.

There is a method:

```
private function BBtoHTML($input_string)
{
    $search = array(
        '/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is',
        '/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/is',
        '/\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/is',
        '/\[s\](.*?)\[\/s\]/is',
        '/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is',
        '/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/is',
        '/\[url\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is',
        '/\[(left|center|right)\](.*?)\[\/(left|center|right)\]/is',
        '/\[font\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/font\]/is',
        '/\[size\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/size\]/is',
        '/\[color\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/color\]/is',
        '\{PAGEBREAK\}',
    ); 

    $replace = array(
        '/<strong>$1</strong>/',
        '/<em>$1</em>/',
        '/<span style="text-decoration: underline;">$1</span>/',
        '/<del>$1</del>/',
        '/<blockquote>$1</blockquote>/',
        '/<code>$1</code>/',
        '/<a href="$1" target="_blank">$2</a>/',
        '/<div style="text-align: $1;">$2</div>/',
        '/<span style="font-family: $1;">$2</span>/',
        '/<span style="font-size: $1;">$2</span>/',
        '/<span style="color: $1;">$2</span>/',
        '/<!--nextpage-->/'
    );

    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $input_string);
}
```

As you might understand on the 645 is the `return preg_replace($search, $replace, $input_string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last pattern you have is `'\{PAGEBREAK\}'`. If you mean to match the literal `\{PAGEBREAK\}` with backslashes included the pattern should be:

```
     '/\\\\{PAGEBREAK\\\\}/',
```

If you mean to match `{PAGEBREAK}` the pattern should be:

```
     '/{PAGEBREAK}/',
```